# is it possible to do two post routes in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a Expressjs Application. It contains public, views, routes folders and app.js file.

I am having a post router for "/" path like this in app.js,

```
app.post('/', store.home_post_handler);
```

and the jade code,

```
#display
    #login        
        form(method='post')
            | Enter your name if you want to be a ninja
            div
                input(type='text', name='username')
                input(type='submit', value='Log In')
```

My question is, is it possible to have a two post methods in a single page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want two forms on a client page, that do different things, the simplest way to differentiate the forms is to have them POST to different URL's by changing the `action` attribute of the form element.

If you require the forms to POST to the same URL, you should use @hexacyanide 's solution.

```
// app.js
app.get('/form', function(req, res){
  res.render('formTemplate');
});

app.post('/form1', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.foo);
});

app.post('/form2', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.bar);
});

// formTemplate.jade
!!!
  body
    form(action='form1', method='post')
      label(for='foo') Foo:
      input(type='text', name='foo', id='foo')
      input(type='submit', value='Submit Foo')
    form(action='form2', method='post')
      label(for='bar') Bar:
      input(type='text', name='bar', id='bar')
      input(type='submit', value='Submit Bar')
```

Comment: Great. Works perfectly.