# How can I differentiate between two POST calls in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

I currently have two different forms on one inven.ejs file:

One for simple description:

```
///inven.ejs
  <form method="POST" value="inven">
     <div id="some-form" style="display: none;">
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td><label for="item">Item</label></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="item" required/></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><label for="text-box-value">Value</label></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><label for="comments">Comments</label></td>
           <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="submit" /></td>
         </tr>          
       </table>
     </div>
   </form>
```

and another for file upload:

```
///inven.ejs
   <div id="fileUp">
     <form id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       <fieldset>
          <input type="file"id="fileSelect">
          <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
       </fieldset>
     </form>
   </div>
```

In express, how can I differentiate between these two posts in my list.js file?

```
router.post('/list', function(req,res){
   // ???
});
```

Do I need two routers? Am I completely doing this incorrectly?
Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Included an image, if it helps?

[image: Image of what I'm attempting to do here]

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278881/is-it-possible-to-do-two-post-routes-in-expressjs), might give this a try. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to have forms post to a different address.

That is, `<form id="fileUpload" action="file_upload" ... >`
Then, if the form is found at `http://server/my_form`, it will post to `http://server/file_upload`

In your Node.js router you need to catch that and done.

---

If you still desire to send both forms to the same address, you can then use hidden fields.

Example: `<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="file_up_form">`. Then in your Node.js you check for the argument `form_type` and check its value.

Comment: If I were to send them to different addresses, is there an easy way I can preserve the user's input data when they return to it without having a popup file upload form?